# Position of :before :after psuedo elements

Tags: css, pseudo-element

1. Is there a way to get the pseudo element `:after`, to obey the width of my container, so it is where the orange ends (after 500px), or will `:after` always kick in where the content inside the element ends?
2. Is the `margin` and/or `padding` of my element, always going to affect the `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements? I thought they have their own margin and padding. At least being able to add a padding to my element shouldn't affect the pseudo elements should it ....

See the following codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wgaYZg

```css
#container {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: orange;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 50px;
}
#container:before {
  background-color: grey;
  content: "before";
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#container:after {
  background-color: grey;
  content: "after";
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">hello world</div>
```

This is what I'm looking to do:

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to get this? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EZjOar

Comment: I have updated my question with an image of what im trying to do.

Comment: OK, so something like this? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rjVQeQ

Comment: yes but to be a pain, i dont want to introduce new elements, and I would like to keep the container as inline-block. I was thinking, perhaps I need to set display: to something else, or some other property on the pseudo elements to get them to behave the way i want.

Comment: I posted an answer with two possible solutions let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand pseudo element `:before` and `:after`, just think them as limited version of `<span>` tags, since a pseudo element can only contain image or plain text as far as I know. They don't have their own `padding` or `margin` by default.

```
<container><:before>normal content<:after></container>
```

To achieve your layout, I suggest to use position tricks without introducing any new tags.

```css
#container {
  background-color: orange;
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 50px 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#container:before,
#container:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
#container:before {
  background-color: grey;
  content: "before";
  width: 100px;
  left: 0;
}
#container:after {
  background-color: grey;
  content: "after";
  width: 100px;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">hello world</div>
```

Otherwise, if you can wrap the plain text into a HTML tag, that would be easy to do with flexbox.

```css
#container {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: orange;
  display: flex;
}
#container span {
  padding: 50px;
  flex: 1;
}
#container:before {
  background-color: grey;
  content: "before";
  width: 100px;
}
#container:after {
  background-color: grey;
  content: "after";
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"><span>hello world</span></div>
```